# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken at login using NGINX and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, csrf, ruby-on-rails-6

I implemented a reverse proxy to access my rails application. However, whenever I try logging in, I am met with a `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error every time whether admin or non-admin accoount. I read that you need to include `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` for it to work but thus far have not for me.

This is my current nginx conf file

```
upstream backend{
        server localhost:3000;
    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl_certificate localhost.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key localhost.key;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        }
```

When I login using localhost:3000,which is the hostname for my rails app, it logs in. So the problem lies with nginx. Also here are my error logs from Rails.

[image]

[image]

Any advice on how to solve?

EDIT: Updated nginx conf file

```
upstream backend{
        server localhost:3000;
    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl_certificate localhost.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key localhost.key;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header origin 'http://localhost:3000';
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fix by adding more headers `X-Forwarded-Ssl on`, `X-Forwarded-Port 443`, `X-Forwarded-Host "your hostname"`, `X-Forwarded-Proto https`.

> CSRF tokens are checked by ActionController (*compares the
>   `request.base_url` with the origin header*)

Comment: It does not work. I have added the following `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443; proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host localhost:3000;` I also did clear cache before implementing the code and restarting the nginx server.

Comment: Also, it may be dumb to ask, but "your hostname" is it the hostname of the nginx server or the rails server?

Comment: Try using `proxy_set_header origin 'http://localhost:3000';` instead X-Forwarded-Host

Comment: It works now, the I have set the 'proxy_set_header_origin 'https://backend', but now it redirects to an empty page. Better than the error page I suppose.

Comment: The solution was inserting `proxy_set_header origin 'https://localhost';` and `proxy_set_header HOST $host;`.

Answer (score 5):

Above solution did not work for me but pushed me to investigate proxy variables.

I could make it work with the following snippet:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Origin https://$http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://web:3000;
  }
  ...
}
```

What was important was:
- using `$http_host` instead of `$host`. In case of non default port number, `$http_host` also contains the port number.
- Setting port number using `$http_host` in `X-Forwarded-Host` header in addition to `Host`
- Setting `Origin`

In particular, setting origin with an incorrect header allowed me to have errors like this in rails and debug it more easily:

`web_1      | W, [2020-05-04T13:30:33.381473 #1]  WARN -- : [cc52d343-5826-4900-b0d8-477714cf9dc4] HTTP Origin header (https://localhost:443) didn't match request.base_url (https://localhost)`

Comment: FWIW, I was able to get it working with only `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`.